# Apache spark + RDD + persist() doubts

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, persist

I am new in apache spark and using scala API. I have 2 questions regarding RDD.

1. How to persist some partitions of a rdd, instead of entire rdd in apache spark? (core rdd implementation provides rdd.persist() and rdd.cache() methods but i do not want to persist entire rdd. I am interested only some partitions to persist.)
2. How to create one empty partition while creating each rdd? (I am using repartition and textFile transformations.In these cases i can get expected number of partitions but i also want one empty partition for each rdd.)

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: why would you want empty partitions? Also why do you only want to persist part of the rdd?

Comment: Mateusz@ because i want to work with incremental join and aggregation operations. so, in future whenever source tables will be updated then i can store only updated data to that empty partitions.

Comment: I want only some part of the rdd to persist because, Each partition has either high/low incremental maintenance overhead. e.g. partition 1 has high overhead since the updates (resulting in updates on partition 1)on the source side are heavy, while partition 2 has low overhead.
Thus, it makes sense to only materialize partition2 in memory not partition 1.

Comment: for the persistene problem you could try splitting the RDD into two or more, one would contain those "highly computationally intensive" records, second the rest and you could just persist the first one. As for the empty partition problem I think I would need to hear much more about it.

Comment: Thanks but how can i persist only single partition?

Comment: It cannot work this way. Even if you could persist a single partition each change results in a new RDD and extended lineage. You could hack Spark to keep long running processes inside executors and implement custom read / write logic but this is a completely different problem.

Comment: @zero323 if i implement a method to persist a partition then i think it will work?

Comment: I don't see this. One way or another you'll have to not only dig into internals but also work against Spark computation model. Splitting computations, as suggested by @MateuszDymczyk is a much better choice. Instead of using RDDs all the way I would consider fast "live" storage as differential buffer and incremental merges with "cold" data.

Comment: @zero323 i did not understand how to persist that computationally intensive partition? because we can not persist partition.

Comment: again, as already said you cannot persist a single partition (by partition I mean an RDD partition). You will have to filter the initial RDD into two separate RDDs, one with the computational heavy entries and one with the light incremental ones. You can persist in memory or on disk the second RDD to reuse it for multiple computation. I think there is a bit of misunderstanding here. You should give a bit of more details here to understand better the problem.

Comment: @PinoSan Thanks for your reply

Comment: @PinoSan if i change core RDD implementation of spark and change or implement a new method to persist a partition of rdd, then i think it will work. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: My guess is it will take you from a month to an year to understand all the internals of spark to make your tiny change and maybe there is a good reason why they don't do that.

Comment: @PinoSan yes you are right. Thanks again !!